# Generics: Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

Tags: java, generics

[image: Error in extends]

I have a class define like this.

```
 public abstract class OptionList<X extends OptionList<X, T>, T extends OptionListItem<X, T>>
extends CommonEntity<OptionList<X, T>>
```

And another class SecuredBean:

```
public abstract class SecuredBean<T extends CommonEntity<T>>
```

Now there is one more class where I need to extends SecureBean and pass OptionList as inbound parameter, something like:

```
public class OptionListBean extends SecuredBean<OptionList<X extends OptionList<X, T>, T extends OptionListItem<X, T>>> {
```

Here it is giving error saying syntax error on token extends, expected.

What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: `OptionList<X extends OptionList<X, T>` ... can you explain what your thinking is here?

Comment: The only way I have seen `extends` used with generics is with upper bounded wildcards, e.g. `? extends OptionList`

Comment: This is the existing code. I can't change anything in there.

Answer (score 2):

Your `OptionListBean` is not generic class but it uses `X` and `T` in definition. It is wrong. Since `SecuredBean` does not take exact classes as template parameters then need to make `OptionListBean` to be generic.

This code compiles for me:

```
class OptionListItem<X, T>{}

class CommonEntity<T>{}

abstract class OptionList<X extends OptionList<X, T>, T extends OptionListItem<X, T>> extends CommonEntity<OptionList<X, T>> {}

abstract class SecuredBean<T extends CommonEntity<T>>{}

class OptionListBean<X extends OptionList<X, T>, T extends OptionListItem<X, T>> extends SecuredBean<OptionList<X, T>> {}
```

I do not know purpose of these classes, therefore cannot say how my suggestion will be useful for your case.